# How can I make my dynamic JSP table scrollable and sortable in ascending and descending order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to display data from a database in a JSP table dynamically. I'd like to make my table scrollable, sortable (ascending and descending), searchable and paginatable.

See this [link](https://www.datatables.net/) for example; you'll find a table with sortable columns, search functionality and paginating.

I would like to achieve something similar to that datatable.

The JSP page looks like this

```
  <html>       
  <body>
  <div class="container" style="overflow:scroll;
                  height:250px;width:100%;overflow:auto">
  <TABLE id="example" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <TR valign=top class="header">
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">ATM Site No</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">ATM Location</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">LHO</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">Cash</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">Non Cash</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">Revenue</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">Up Time</TH>
  <TH bgcolor="#008000">Up Time Date</TH>
  </TR>
  </thead>
  <s:iterator  value="uptimeBeans">
  <tbody>
  <TR valign=top>
  <TD><s:property value="ATM_Site_No"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="ATM_Location"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="LHO"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="Cash"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="Non Cash"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="Revenue"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="Up Time"/></TD>
  <TD><s:property value="Up Time Date"/></TD>
  </TR>
  </tbody>
  </s:iterator>
  </TABLE>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you can consider using datatable itself, you can convert normal html table to datatable by using datatable jquery. Writing sorting by yourself is big effort ,better use some existing framework like datatable shown in your question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call this script for using datable after adding jquery and datatable js :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "scrollY": 200,
    "scrollX": true,
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]

} );
} );
```

Here, 1 is column no. needed to sort , you can change it as per need.

Refer [datatable intialization](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

[datatable sorting](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)
[datatable scrolling](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this script for dynamic sorting in datatable.

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
      "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
   } );
} );

please refer this URL for dynamic sorting in datatable:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html
```